# Running Socket listening Thread inside JAR in android

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable, serversocket, socketexception

I am trying to build a JAR which continuously listen to a particular socket in a thread. I have developed this in Android Service, now I want to convert my coding into JAR. So far I  have made the necessary changes but I am getting stuck on code-line(App crashes)
`client = serverSocket.accept();`

I have deleted the code of printing my logs in the below code, but I have logs in every catch block and in between lines as well. I have not received any exception in catch blocks but my UI app through which I am using my JAR, its getting force close! Any idea why this behaviour?

```
public void startServer() {

    try
    {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
    }catch (UnknownHostException e1) {}


    if (serverThread == null) 
    {
   serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
   serverThread.start();
    }
}


public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

public synchronized void run() {

    try {

        client = null;

            while (true) {                      

                try {

                    client = serverSocket.accept();

                    requestReaderThread = new Thread(new RequestReaderThread());
                    requestReaderThread.start();
                }catch (Exception e) {}
            }   

    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

};

Comment: -1 for unbelievably terrible formatting.

Comment: Thats because i am new to this, respect freshers maaartinus.

Comment: It's much better now, but still a pain to read. One good piece of advice: [Don't swallow exceptions](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2003/04/28/swallowing_exceptions_dont_do_it). You're just making your code longer and totally crappy. Only catch them where you absolutely have to or really can handle.